# Docker command not found on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am running windows 10 pro, and have Virtual Box installed and then installed ubuntu desktop as vm.
Then I followed step by step to install docker on Ubuntu as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

And when it comes to tasting the pudding..

it says sudo: docker: command not found.

What am I missing.

Comment: Please try this.  https://blog.jayway.com/2017/04/19/running-docker-on-bash-on-windows/

Comment: Are you trying to run `docker` from inside the VM, or the host?  Can you provide the complete set of commands you actually ran and any relevant application source code?

Comment: Why do you want to install docker inside Ubuntu VM any particular reasons? You can install docker toolbox if you prefer virtual box or have other VM's in Virtual Box.If you can survive without Virtual Box install Docker Desktop for Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved it today.

The reason I am getting this error is because the packages are not getting installed in the first place. I am getting Hash sum mismatch error. I was blindly assuming that the installation is successful. I have raised a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224110/hash-sum-mismatch-error-when-i-try-to-install-docker/1224213#1224213) and answered it as well.

I first downloaded the packages and then installed them. See the [ans](https://askubuntu.com/a/1224213/653959).